# Calling a DBus serivce from a pure QML plasmoid

Tags: qt, qml, dbus, kde-plasma

Could anybody suggest me a tutorial or example how to call a custom DBus service (on the system bus) from a pure QML KDE plasmoid, without an intermediate layer? Is it possible at all?

The standard plasmoids like [org.kde.plasma.battery](https://github.com/KDE/plasma-workspace/tree/master/applets/batterymonitor) or [org.kde.kscreen](https://invent.kde.org/plasma/kscreen/-/tree/master/plasmoid/package) use the DataSource approach, which likely requires a shared library or other code in C++. Other plasmoids invoke wrappers (e.g. in python) to talk with a DBus service.

So the question: is it possible to call a given D-Bus service directly from QML/JS without an intermediate layer, at most by importing some (standard) KDE/QT/plasma library?

Comment: I don't think that QML can natively work with DBus, you probably need some plugin/extension.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I still keep hope alive :-)

Comment: If you are using the org.kde.kwin module, you can create a DBusCall object to call methods. It is not documented anywhere except for the KDE source code, and I had an incredibly hard time finding it. The module may not be available for plasmoids, but it is available for KWin scripts.